# How to add MS unicodes to a heatmap in R?

Tags: r, unicode, complexheatmap

I have a dataset where I have manually assigned some unicodes to row names (the `vars` column in my data example below):

[image]

I read this data into R, convert it to a matrix with the `vars` column set to be rownames for the matrix, and then use the `complexheatmap` package to plot a heatmap - however, it is not accepting the unicodes I've added to the  row names, instead I get this:

```
Heatmap(data, name = "log p-value", column_title = "Sets", 
         row_title = "Vars", 
         column_names_rot = 45,
         cluster_rows = TRUE, cluster_columns = FALSE, col = col_fun)
Warning messages:
1: In grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  : conversion failure on 'var1�' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot substituted for <e0>
2: In grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  : conversion failure on 'var2�' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot substituted for <e0>
3: In grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  : conversion failure on 'var3�' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot substituted for <e0>
4: In grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  : conversion failure on 'var4�' in 'mbcsToSbcs': dot substituted for <a0>
```

The output plot is then blank for the rownames with unicodes. How can I get this heatmap to accept the unicodes as they are in the rownames? So far I've only found similar questions that are focused on ggplot and not using other packages like complexheatmap. Any help or guidance is appreciated.

Edit: having a go at adding example code, but when I take this directly from R it doesn't let me include the unicodes as they actually look in the image above (e.g. †, ‡):

```
data <- structure(c(27.88329977, 18.12896031, 17.83458703, 25.67060325, 
23.32033202, 24.50406143, 16.98524839, 20.43345407, 19.18854732, 
15.17015206, 20.68765274, 17.97664243, 17.5016736, 17.66349143, 
17.57835389, 17.33819738, 14.99944861, 15.04948794, 10.6137363, 
9.360755894, 20.16400165, 13.88834838, 11.18364291, 8.568037579, 
6.621062251), .Dim = c(5L, 5L), .Dimnames = list(c("var1\xe0", 
"var2\xe0", "var3\xe0", "var4\xa0", "va5\xa0"
), c("col1", "col2", "col3", 
"col4", "col5")))
```

Comment: Please  [edit] your question and share a [mcve]. Note that pictures of data and/or code are useless…

Comment: Thank you for your help, I've had a go at adding in an example, please let me know if anything else is needed, I'm not sure how to get it right for the unicodes

Comment: Runs smoothly with hard-coded `… .Dimnames = list(c("var1‡", "var2×", "var3‡", "var4†", "va5†"), …` (where `row.names(data)` returns `[1] "var1‡" "var2×" "var3‡" "var4†" "va5†"`. In your example are warnings about `var1�`, `var2�` etc. etc. where the `�` is Unicode `U+FFFD`, UTF-8 bytes `\xEF\xBF\xBD` _Replacement Character_ (no `latin1` code). Hence, an error must be where you read a dataframe (see the picture), supposedly from a `csv` file?